# Identifying and fixing/removing odd bathtub drain stopper

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I have a tub with a broken drain stopper consisting of metal rod(s) inside the drain assembly, below the in-tub drain connected up through the overflow. As best I can tell, it looks something like the following ASCII-art diagram:

```
                   |    |
            overflow __ |
     TUB           |  | |
                   |  | |
                   |  | |
  _____drain_______|  | |
     _________________| |
  _________________     |
                   |    |
```

but perhaps it's more like:

```
                   |    |
            overflow __ |
     TUB           |  | |
                   |  | |
                   |  | |
 ______drain_______|  | |
|    _________________| |
|     __________________|
|    |
```

It's non-operative and I have no idea how it was ever intended to operate, but it makes the tub drain very slowly. Any idea what it's called, and/or how to fix/remove enough of it so that it does not interfere with draining?

Comment: The drain may be plugged with hair and soap scum. This is one place I will use a foaming drain cleaner. Pouring some down the drain and into the overflow vent. They rarely wear out but regularly get hard to operate with buildup of soap and hair.

Comment: @EdBeal: I've used various approaches to clean it out over and over again, only to have it clog again within a few weeks. The stopper does not work because the handle on the overflow plate and whatever it's supposed to use to connect to the mechanism behind it are broken off, and the stopper it was supposed to lift was removed long ago. So I'm just looking for a way to get it out or out of the way.